# Using conditional statement to subtract scalar from pandas df column gives ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, scalar, truthiness

I'm trying to execute:

```
if df_trades.loc[:, 'CASH'] != 0: df_trades.loc[:, 'CASH'] -= commission
```

and then I get the error. `df_trades.loc[:, 'CASH']` is a column of floats. I want to subtract the scalar `commission` from each entry in that column.

For example, `df_trades.loc[:, 'CASH']` prints out

```
2011-01-10   -2557.0000
2011-01-11       0.0000
2011-01-12       0.0000
2011-01-13   -2581.0000
```

If `commission` is `1`, I want the result:

```
2011-01-10   -2558.0000
2011-01-11       0.0000
2011-01-12       0.0000
2011-01-13   -2582.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where`

```
commission = -1
df['CASH'] = np.where(df['CASH'] != 0, df['CASH'] + commission , df['CASH'])
```

or `df.where` i.e

```
df['CASH'] = df['CASH'].where(df['CASH'] == 0,df['CASH']+commission)
```

or `df.mask`

```
df['CASH'] = df['CASH'].mask(df['CASH'] != 0 ,df['CASH']+commission)
```

```
Date
2011-01-10   -2558.0
2011-01-11       0.0
2011-01-12       0.0
2011-01-13   -2582.0
Name: CASH, dtype: float64
```

```
%%timeit
commission = -1
df['CASH'] = np.where(df['CASH'] != 0, df['CASH'] + commission , df['CASH'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 750 µs per loop

%%timeit
df['CASH'].mask(df['CASH'] != 0 ,df['CASH']+commission)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop

%%timeit
df['CASH'].where(df['CASH'] == 0,df['CASH']+commission)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

%%timeit
df.loc[df['CASH'] != 0, 'CASH'] += commission
100 loops, best of 3: 2.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is Numpy or Pandas more efficient for this?

Comment: Is pshep123's solution about the same as well?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 I added the timings for better speed comparision

Comment: Thanks for the timing Bharath. Didn't realize `where()` was so much faster.  Off to refactor a couple thousand, `.loc[]` statements...

Comment: Would also like to thank you Bharath. Do you mind sharing the Pandas way as well?

Comment: @pshep123 Its because boolean indexing and setting the value is a costly process than conditionally getting array and assigning it to a column name.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 `df.where` is a pandas way of doing this. There's another option with mask too. Let me put that here.

Comment: Can you add the times of mask and df.where

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`df.loc[df['CASH'] != 0, 'CASH'] -= 1`

Comment: Is this the most Pythonic solution given I'm using Pandas and Numpy?

Comment: I'm not the arbiter on pythonic code, but it works and is clean. Nor have I tested the speed, so give them both a shot and see what works best for you.