# How to count instances following a condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing 18 unique IDs, each having one column of interest for which I want to count instances where its values are greater than or less than 0.25
For those that are greater than 0.25, I want to subtract a value from them, to then graph the resulting values in a column scatter plot. How would I go about counting those instances using pandas and to extract those >0.25 values to have those values available to put into the scatter plot?

Comment: [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) ... [Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/cookbook.html#cookbook) ... [Conditionally subtract single value from a column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46830447/2823755) ...  [Tutorials](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html#tutorials)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is pretty broad. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Demo data

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"num":[0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4]})
print(data)

   num
0  0.1
1  0.3
2  0.1
3  0.4
```

Filter the values that less than 0.25

```
great_than = data[data.num > 0.25]
print(great_than)

   num
1  0.3
3  0.4
```

Comment: that's what I did and this method returns boolean values for the data. I wanted the actual values instead
Also, if the column I'm working with has a dot in it, how would i reference it? i.e. "data.seg.mean" would produce an error

Comment: @RiveraJackson I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you can add some demo data and make clear what result you want to get.